# More informative SASS error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

How can I get more informative error messages from SASS?  It's a Rails 3.1 app that works fine in development mode, in production all I get is:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home

Showing C:/documents/projects/aaa_0003/implementation/ror/aaa0003/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

0.3 is not a color for `alpha'
  (in C:/documents/projects/aaa_0003/implementation/ror/aaa0003/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
Extracted source (around line #7):

4:  <head>
5:      <title><%= title %></title>
6:      <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
7:      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
8:      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Gem file is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'pg', '0.11.0'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'rake'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "nested_form"
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end


group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
  gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'   ## for creating loads of random users to test the site with.
end

group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku'
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you pre-compile your assets? If so, SASS shouldn't even be needed in production env.

Comment: why is sass-rails not in your assets group?

Comment: @daniel https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/38#issuecomment-2046678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up just manually searching through my .css.scss files and found the offending line, which indeed was trying to use a deprecated / broken css styling rule to set opacity to 0.3.  All working now.