# Poor time performance of 'rake assets:precompile'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, performance, pre-compilation

Running:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Takes about 6 minutes for 15 .js files of about 250kb total.  It should not take this long surely?  I see the 'Microsoft Console Based Script Host' working flat out for most of this time.

What would people recommend / know is possible?
Is there a way to replace this with Ruby-Racer or another javascript V8 engine implementation?  OR to find out the problem in my code that's causing the long time?
Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Which server are you running? Is it Ubuntu, Debian, Mac?
Make sure you have this in your Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem "libv8"
  gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'
end
```

See this page for more info: 
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2537

You can also try to remove unused files in your `app/assets/*` folders. 
Time is most spent on JS compilation.

Comment: How do I find the unused files in my app/assets folders? For example, how do I know which are unused jquery components, or ckeditor components?

Comment: You have to analyze the application and identify the assets which are no longer relevant. And if possible, remove them so that they no longer contribute to the assets compilation.